# Unable to save blank multiselect value in system configuration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml, backend-model

I have created multiselect in `system.xml` with `backend_model` and customize `afterSave` function and return `parent::afterSave()`.

```
<field id="populatavailablebanknetbanking" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Available Bank for Netbanking (Popular)</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Availablebanknetbanking</source_model>
    <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Backend\Popularbanknetbanking</backend_model>
    <comment>This selected depends on the Available Bank for Netbanking options. You can only select from the selection made above for the popular bank.</comment>
</field>
```

It's working fine with saving multiselect value in the database but when I unselect all the options from multiselect, it saves recently saved options from the database instead of clear the options from the database.

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
<can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
```

Like:

```
<field id="list" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Customer Groups</label>
    <source_model>Commercepundit\Simpleshipping\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Customer\Group</source_model>
    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
</field>
```

Answer (score 5):

Magento have property **`<can_be_empty>`**. Which allows you to save blank value in database.

```
<field id="populatavailablebanknetbanking" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Available Bank for Netbanking (Popular)</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Availablebanknetbanking</source_model>
    <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Backend\Popularbanknetbanking</backend_model>
    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
    <comment>This selected depends on the Available Bank for Netbanking options. You can only select from the selection made above for the popular bank.</comment>
</field>
```

Answer (score 5):

> The `<can_be_empty/>` tag is used with multiselect fields. The short
>   version is, if you wish to a allow “no selection” to be a valid
>   configuration, use this field.
>
> What happens behind the scenes is if **can_be_empty** is **true**, the
>   system renders a hidden field on the System Configuration page

File: **lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Multiselect.php**

```
if ($this->getCanBeEmpty()) 
{
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . parent::getName() . '" value="" />';
}
```

> which ensure the form processing code will accept an **empty selection**.